# Pipe bytes from subprocess to file-like object in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'd like accomplish the following in Python. I want to call a subprocess (`ffmpeg` in this case, using the [ffmpy3](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpy3/) wrapper) and directly pipe the process' output on to a file-like object that can be consumed by another function's `open()` call. Since audio and video data can become quite big, I explicitly don't ever want to load the process' output into memory as a whole, but only "stream" it in a buffered fashion. Here is some example code.

```
async def convert_and_process(file: FileIO):
    ff = ffmpy3.FFmpeg(
        inputs={str(file.name): None},
        outputs={'pipe:1': '-y -ac 1 -ar 16000 -acodec pcm_s16le -f wav'}
    )

    stdout: StreamReader = (await ff.run_async(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)).stdout

    with wave.open(help_needed, 'rb') as wf:
        # do stuff with wave file
        pass
```

[Here](https://github.com/wchill/ffmpy3/blob/master/ffmpy3.py#L134) is the code of `run_async`, it's just a simple wrapper around `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()`.

My problem is basically just to turn the `StreamReader` returned by `run_async()` into a file-like object that can be consumed by `wave.open()`. Moreover, does this approach actually not load all output into memory, as `Popen.wait()` or `Popen.communicate()` would do?

I was thinking that [`os.pipe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20pipe#os.pipe) might be useful, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is the true representation of your ultimate goal (read audio samples in blocks) then you can accomplish it much easier just with FFmpeg and its `subprocess.Popen.stdout`. If there are more to it than using `wave` library to read a memory-mapped .wav file, then please ignore this answer or clarify.

First a shameless plug, if you are willing to try another library, my [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) can do what you want to do. Here is an example:

```py
import ffmpegio

#audio stream reader
with ffmpegio.open(file,'ra', blocksize=1024, ac=1, ar=16000, 
                   sample_fmt='s16le') as f:
    for block in f: # block: [1024xchannels] ndarray
        do_your_thing(block)
```

`blocksize` argument sets the number of samples to retrieve at a time (so 1024 audio samples in this example).

This library is still pretty young, and if you have any issues please report on its GitHub Issues board.

Second, if you prefer to implement it yourself, it's actually fairly straight forward if you know the FFmpeg output stream formats AND you need only one stream (multiple streams could also be done easily under non-Windows, I think). For your example above, try the following:

```py
ff = ffmpy3.FFmpeg(
        inputs={str(file.name): None},
        outputs={'pipe:1': '-y -ac 1 -ar 16000 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le'}
    )
stdout = (await ff.run_async(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)).stdout

nsamples = 1024 # read 1024 samples
itemsize = 2 # bytes, int16x1channel

while True:
    try:
        b = stdout.read(nsamples*itemsize)
        # you may need to check for len(b)=0 as well, not sure atm
    except BrokenPipeError:
        break
    x = np.frombuffer(b, nsamples, np.int16)
    # do stuff with audio samples in x
```

Note that I changed `-f wav` to `-f s16le` so only the raw samples are sent to `stdout`. Then `stdout.read(n)` is essentially identical to `wave.readframes(n)` except for what their `n`'s mean.

Comment: Thanks, especially the first suggestion looks promising. But I'd like to avoid pulling in whole numpy just for reading audio samples. FFmpeg is mainly used for conversion, e.g. from MP3, etc. to WAV. 

While converting and reading audio samples is actually my specific use case, I'd still like to know how to solve this in general. Shouldn't be too hard to do simple piping in Python, without reading the intermediary data into memory or another file, is it?

Comment: Gotcha. My library is for those who processes audio and video data in Python, and doing so almost always requires numpy (could be wrong tho). To me, "just reading audio samples" itself justifies numpy because python do not recognize int/float formats that's used for audio samples, and numpy is the only library which makes it generically possible AFAIK.

Comment: As for `os.pipe`, have you actually tried to pass `(await ff.run_async(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)).stdout` directly to `wave`? `stdout` is an `os.pipe` on its own, so if that doesn't work, you may not be able to accomplish it. It may not work if the FFmpeg wav muxer requires to seek its output (which you cannot do with a pipe)

Comment: What `ff.run_async(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)).stdout` returns is a `StreamReader`, which can't be passed to `open()` and also only has an async `read()` method (returns a Coroutine).

Comment: Oh I see (not familiar with `asyncio` derivatives of FFmpeg libraries). How about if you use the regular `ffmpy`? That one should return a buffered `os.pipe` as `stdout`.

Comment: To me it looks more like ffmpy's `run()` method returns an already read byte array, see https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#using-pipe-protocol.

Comment: You're correct I'm not familiar with `ffmpy` and assumed it's similar to `ffmpeg-python`. Try `ffmpeg-python` then, I know that its `run_async()` method returns a plain `subprocess.Popen`